# Chromium Embedded: How to scale a website to account for higher DPI (CEF3)

Tags: delphi, chromium-embedded

I use CEF3 for displaying a web page in my Windows application. It works fine, but it doesn't scale if Windows has higher DPI settings (e.g. 150%). I don't expect it to do this automatically but I also don't find any property which can be set to tell chromium to scale. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: As far as I remember, you can only set the [`ZoomLevel`](http://magpcss.org/ceforum/apidocs3/projects/(default)/CefBrowserHost.html#SetZoomLevel(double)) to the `Chromium.Browser.Host.ZoomLevel` property.

Comment: Thanks this was the "hidden" property. I just didn't found it.

Comment: A new question arised: ZoomLevel is unfortunatelly not a zoom factor. "-1.0" seem to scale the webpage to 50% of its original size. "3.0" scales it to 200%, "0.0" ist 100%, "1.0" is a bit bigger than 100%...what's the formular for that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Zoom and scale are different things as you already noticed. I think this is the formula you are looking for:

```
    public void SetScaleFactor(double scale)
    {
        double zoomLevel = Math.Log(scale, 1.2);
        this._browserHost.SetZoomLevel(zoomLevel);
    }
```

You can give it a try and see the difference with zoom.

Good luck!